# What does blkid stand for?

Tags: linux, command-line, rhel, command

What does the command `blkid` stand for?

I want a way to remember it. Also, what is it often used for?

Comment: man page is your friend ... from a terminal issue ... man blkid

Answer (score 6):

It stands for "Block Identification". 1*

I general, using `whatis` can provide info about a command:
 `whatis blkid`

A block (device) is a file that provides *buffered* access to hardware.
E.g a hard-drive. Futher info:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Device_file#Block_devices

Each block device listed by `blkid` has a unique universal Identifier (UUID). `blkid` allows you to see a listing of these identifiers.

Example output, (note the 'UUID'):
`/dev/sda1: LABEL="ESP" UUID="A21C-9B25" TYPE="vfat" PARTLABEL="EFI system partition" PARTUUID="99cbea91-0fab-424a-81d9-dee679c6e358"`

This is often used in conjuncion with `mount` command. The reason is that /dev/xyz might be re-assigned to some other letter when hardware is swapped, where as the UUID is generally constant.  e.g:
 `mount UUID="A21C-...." /mnt/myDisk`

[1] src: http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/ubuntu-linux/177686-what-does-blkid-stand.html

Comment: A good question, but saying `blkid` means `Block ID` is not a good answer - perhaps it is to you, but is it enough for others? (It isn't for me). *id* does not stand for *ID*, that's just the same thing in capital letters – and what does `block` mean? The link you refer mentions a utility, `whatis`, which prints this: *- command-line utility to locate/print block device attributes*. From that it is reasonable to assume that `id` does mean `identification`, but I am still wondering what a `block device` is. Put all of this into your answer so there is no need to chase links, then +1

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I pimped the answer. Let me know what you think.

Comment: Great! That certainly got me aware that `blkid` is more than just an expanded abbreviation. +1 :), and I've already given a +1 for the question. The question really caught my eye,

Comment: It would have also helped if the answer contained detailed information about the various fields displayed as in output of `blkid`